# TYPO3 7.6 Backend module table DataTable not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I've been searching for quite a while but neither solution worked.

I have created a backend module which shall display orders in a table. I achieved creating a table containing the wanted information BUT I need some more functionality and I thought there would be an easy way.

The table should be sortable, filterable and searchable - functions that TYPO3 uses for displaying datasets in the backend already.

I have tried to make use of the DataTables which are already included by the core of TYPO3 and should be easily accessible according to the following links:

1. https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/210780/
2. https://typo3.com/blog/how-to-use-javascript-in-typo3s-backend/
3. [TYPO3 backend modul DataTable is no function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925678/typo3-backend-modul-datatable-is-no-function)

I added a js-file according to the answer from Philipp Wrann in the first link:

/Resources/Public/JavaScript/OrderingTables.js:

```
define('TYPO3/CMS/GiPdShop', ['jquery', 'datatables'], function($) {

     var OrderingTables = {};

     // Initialize dataTables
     OrderingTables.initializeDataTables = function() {
         $('#orders-table').DataTable();
     };

     $(document).ready(function() {
         // Initialize the view
         OrderingTables.initializeDataTables();
     });

});
```

As there are no errors and the file is included if I check in the dev-tools I believe this is not a bad approach. To use the file I added the following to the `<f:be.container>` in the template:

```
includeRequireJsModules="{0: 'TYPO3/CMS/GiPdShop/OrderingTables'}"
```

Yet it doesn't create a DataTable, no added classes to the rows or cells of the table and thus I assume that there is some kind of error, maybe a missing configuration, maybe another option I missed out somehow.

The only other solutions I found so far seem rather complicated and I would love to keep it as simple as possible (I am not a professional in TYPO3 (yet) and the module should already be functional).

Can someone see a mistake I haven't found? Is it even possible to add the wanted functionality in such an easy way?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you add an alert("Hello World"); to the document ready, does it appear?

Comment: I didn't even come up with a test as simple as that.... -.- @PaulBeck No, it doesn't appear. And now I found where I was mistaken... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a stupid little thing I was missing.

The path 'TYPO3/CMS/GiPdShop' in the definition was missing the module.
So the correct path would be 'TYPO3/CMS/GiPdShop/OrderingTables', the same I have added in the template.

Really stupid but maybe this helps someone someday who gets stuck as well...

@PaulBeck thanks again!