# How to make RequireJS resolve namespace correctly for TYPO3 BE?

Tags: namespaces, requirejs, typo3, typo3-8.x

I want to load additional JS in the TYPO3 back end. I'm using requireJS as in [the official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Loading/Index.html).

In ext_localconf.php I'm trying to load my JS like this:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE=="BE" )   {
    $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/ExtensionName/EventEndDateValidator');
}
```

In my browser console I get an error like:

> Error: Script error for
>   "TYPO3/CMS/ExtensionName/EventEndDateValidator"
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

and

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “http://localhost/typo3/TYPO3/CMS/ExtensionName/EventEndDateValidator.js?bust=6b9250465c29da98dea71ea9e447e7db2d3ccea3”.
>   index.php:1

So the name space is not resolving. [The docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Extensions/Index.html) and [@DAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42970446/4062341) say that it is enough to place the JS-file in the `EXT:extension_name/Resources/Public/JavaScript` directory.

My JS-File is this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    var EventEndDateValidator = {
        sayings: [
            'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
            'Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack'
        ]
    };

    EventEndDateValidator.say = function() {
        alert(EventEndDateValidator.sayings[Math.floor(Math.random() * EventEndDateValidator.sayings.length)]);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialize the view
        EventEndDateValidator.say();
    });
});
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify one thing you wrote, you've to replace `ExtensionName` with the name of your own extension - not sure if you did it:

Assume your extension has the key `wonderful_extension`, then the name usually would be `WonderfulExtension`.

Then in the file ext_localconf.php you've to write it like this:

```php
if (TYPO3_MODE=="BE" )   {
    $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/WonderfulExtension/EventEndDateValidator');
}
```

According to the code you use currently, the extension key had to be `extension_name` with the name `ExtensionName`, it wouldn't be reasonable probably to use these strings really. In the documentation they've to be seen as variables to be replaced with your own values.

Comment: The fault was exactly there. I had a typo in my extensions folder on my development computer that I carried over to the name space call.