# Custom LinkHandler

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I am looking for a working example of a custom LinkHandler for TYPO3 CMS 11. The examples in the [core documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/LinkHandling/Linkhandler/CustomLinkHandlers.html) as well as in the extension [t3docs/examples](https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/t3docs-examples) in version 11.1.1, all do not work.

Error message:
Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->linkBrowser" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/LinkBrowser.html). The following paths were checked: /var/www/html/www/typo3/sysext/recordlist/Resources/Private/Templates/LinkBrowser/

EXT:some_extension/Classes/LinkHandler/GitHubLinkHandler.php

```
<?php
namespace T3docs\Examples\LinkHandler;

# use ...
use TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\LinkHandlerInterface;

class GitHubLinkHandler implements LinkHandlerInterface
{
   protected $linkAttributes = ['target', 'title', 'class', 'params', 'rel'];
   protected $view;
   protected $configuration;

   /**
   * Initialize the handler
   *
   * @param AbstractLinkBrowserController $linkBrowser
   * @param string $identifier
   * @param array $configuration Page TSconfig
   */
   public function initialize(AbstractLinkBrowserController $linkBrowser, $identifier, array $configuration)
   {
      $this->linkBrowser = $linkBrowser;
      $this->iconFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(IconFactory::class);
      $this->view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
      $this->view->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName('examples');
      $this->view->setTemplateRootPaths([GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Templates/LinkBrowser')]);
      $this->configuration = $configuration;
   }

   /**
   * Checks if this is the handler for the given link
   *
   * Also stores information locally about currently linked issue
   *
   * @param array $linkParts Link parts as returned from TypoLinkCodecService
   *
   * @return bool
   */
   public function canHandleLink(array $linkParts)
   {
      if (isset($linkParts['url']['github'])) {
         $this->linkParts = $linkParts;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   /**
   * Format the current link for HTML output
   *
   * @return string
   */
   public function formatCurrentUrl(): string
   {
      return $this->linkParts['url']['github'];
   }


   /**
   * Render the link handler
   *
   * @param ServerRequestInterface $request
   *
   * @return string
   */
   public function render(ServerRequestInterface $request): string
   {
      GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PageRenderer::class)
         ->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Examples/GitHubLinkHandler');

      $this->view->assign('project', $this->configuration['project']);
      $this->view->assign('action', $this->configuration['action']);
      $this->view->assign('github', !empty($this->linkParts) ? $this->linkParts['url']['github'] : '');
      return $this->view->render('GitHub');
   }

   /**
   * @return string[] Array of body-tag attributes
   */
   public function getBodyTagAttributes(): array
   {
      return [];
   }

   /**
   * @return array
   */
   public function getLinkAttributes()
   {
      return $this->linkAttributes;
   }

   /**
   * @param string[] $fieldDefinitions Array of link attribute field definitions
   * @return string[]
   */
   public function modifyLinkAttributes(array $fieldDefinitions)
   {
      return $fieldDefinitions;
   }

   /**
   * We don't support updates since there is no difference to simply set the link again.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
   public function isUpdateSupported()
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example seems to be broken

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/97738#note-3

My solution was to extend the `AbstractLinkHandler` and implement the `LinkHandlerInterface` like described in the issue.

```
class CustomUrlLinkHandler extends AbstractLinkHandler implements LinkHandlerInterface
```

An other strange part was the "Namespace" for the [Javascript module](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Loading/Index.html), which is not logically for me and not fully described in the docs but mentioned in a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55671203/9015191), anyway this part will change in [further versions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Backend/JavaScript/ES6/Index.html#requirejs-migration)

`Copy from David:`

Assume your extension has the key `wonderful_extension`, then the name usually would be `WonderfulExtension`.

Then in the file ext_localconf.php you've to write it like this:

```php
if (TYPO3_MODE=="BE" )   {
    $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
    $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/WonderfulExtension/EventEndDateValidator');
}
```

According to the code you use currently, the extension key had to be `extension_name` with the name `ExtensionName`, it wouldn't be reasonable probably to use these strings really. In the documentation they've to be seen as variables to be replaced with your own values.

Comment: The old RequireJS namespace logic is explained in the documentation here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Extensions/Index.html#use-requirejs-in-your-own-extension .... The namespace is TYPO3/CMS/<EXTKEY>, <EXTKEY> is your extension key in UpperCamelCase, e.g. foo_bar = FooBar and points to your <EXTKEY>/Resources/Public/JavaScript. The relative path/filename in that folder matches to the namespace. for core sysexts and own extension. fully explained and a simple logic.